pySerialTransfer Two Way Communication Issues
I wrote a minimal two way python and serial communication script that sends an integer to the arduino. Then, the arduino increments the integer and sends it back over serial.
comm.py
from time import sleep
from pySerialTransfer import pySerialTransfer as txfer


class struct:
    control = 0

class receivestruct:
    status = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        testStruct = struct
        rstruct =receivestruct 
        link = txfer.SerialTransfer('COM7')
        
        link.open()
        sleep(2)
        
        counter = 0
    
        while True:
            sendSize = 0
            
            testStruct.control = counter
            
            sendSize = link.tx_obj(testStruct.control, start_pos=sendSize)
            
            link.send(sendSize)

            print('sent')
            #sleep(0.5)

            read_correctly = False
            while (read_correctly == False):
                try:
                    if not (link.available()):
                        pass

                    recSize = 0
                    # this section returns errors with can't read str as int 
                    rstruct.status = link.rx_obj(obj_type='i', start_pos=recSize)
                    counter = rstruct.status
                    recSize += txfer.STRUCT_FORMAT_LENGTHS['i']

                    print(rstruct.status)
                    read_correctly = True
                except:
                    pass

        
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        link.close()

arduino.ino
#include "SerialTransfer.h"


SerialTransfer myTransfer;

uint32_t rcontrol;

uint32_t control;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  myTransfer.begin(Serial);
}

void loop()
{
  if(myTransfer.available())
  {
    // use this variable to keep track of how many
    // bytes we've processed from the receive buffer
    uint16_t recSize = 0;

    recSize = myTransfer.rxObj(rcontrol, recSize);


    control = rcontrol + 1;
    uint16_t sendSize = 0;


    sendSize = myTransfer.txObj(control, sendSize);

    myTransfer.sendData(sendSize);
    
  }
}

Now, I thought this would work properly. However, here is the console log, where it seems like python is not reading the incremented value properly, and only reads the correct incremented value every n attempts:
115
sent
115
sent
116
sent
116
sent
116
sent
116
sent
116
sent
116
sent
116
sent
116
sent
116
sent
117
sent
117
sent
117
sent
117
sent
117
sent
117
sent
117
sent
117
sent
117
sent
118
sent
118
sent
118
sent
118
sent
118
sent
118
sent
118
sent
118
sent
118
sent
119
sent
119
sent
119
sent
119
sent
119
sent
119
sent
119
sent
119
sent

I tried the two way example for pySerialTransfer here, but it appears to use an outdated version of the library that is no longer supported. Any idea why I am seeing these issue with two way serial communication?

I installed pySerialTransfer version 2.6.9 on my Python setup and SerialTransfer version 3.1.3 for my Arduino Uno.
You say you wanted to send a single integer value so I followed the datum examples in the pySerialTransfer library.
I end up with the following for the code on the Arduino to receive an integer, increment it, and return the new value:
#include "SerialTransfer.h"


SerialTransfer myTransfer;

int y;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  myTransfer.begin(Serial);
}


void loop()
{
  if(myTransfer.available())
  {
    myTransfer.rxObj(y);
    y++;
    myTransfer.sendDatum(y);
  }
  delay(500);
}

I'm using an Arduino Uno so an int is stored as a 16-bit (2-byte) value. This yields a range of -32,768 to 32,767. This meant for the Python code I had to override the object type in the Python code to be a 2-byte signed integer using the information in the source code for rx_obj:
https://github.com/PowerBroker2/pySerialTransfer/blob/74067630dcac6bc0db8925a715a7f9e31ea55bd5/pySerialTransfer/pySerialTransfer.py#L319-L321
and tx_obj:
https://github.com/PowerBroker2/pySerialTransfer/blob/74067630dcac6bc0db8925a715a7f9e31ea55bd5/pySerialTransfer/pySerialTransfer.py#L242-L243
This was the Python code I used for testing:
from time import sleep
from pySerialTransfer import pySerialTransfer as txfer

y = 0
send_data = True
port_id = 'xxxx'  # Insert actual value e.g: 'COM7'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        link = txfer.SerialTransfer(port_id)
        link.open()
        sleep(5)

        while True:
            if send_data:
                sendSize = link.tx_obj(y, val_type_override='h')
                link.send(sendSize)
                send_data = False
                print("Data sent:", y, end=' -+- ')
            if not send_data and link.available():
                y = link.rx_obj(obj_type='h')
                print("Data received:", y)
                send_data = True
            if link.status <= 0:
                if link.status == txfer.CRC_ERROR:
                    print('ERROR: CRC_ERROR')
                elif link.status == txfer.PAYLOAD_ERROR:
                    print('ERROR: PAYLOAD_ERROR')
                elif link.status == txfer.STOP_BYTE_ERROR:
                    print('ERROR: STOP_BYTE_ERROR')

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    finally:
        link.close()

Which gave me the following output:
Data sent: 0 -+- Data received: 1
Data sent: 1 -+- Data received: 2
Data sent: 2 -+- Data received: 3
Data sent: 3 -+- Data received: 4
Data sent: 4 -+- Data received: 5
Data sent: 5 -+- Data received: 6
Data sent: 6 -+- Data received: 7
Data sent: 7 -+- Data received: 8
Data sent: 8 -+- Data received: 9
Data sent: 9 -+- Data received: 10
Data sent: 10 -+- Data received: 11
Data sent: 11 -+- Data received: 12
Data sent: 12 -+- Data received: 13
Data sent: 13 -+- Data received: 14
Data sent: 14 -+- Data received: 15
Data sent: 15 -+- Data received: 16


The GitHub version of the pySerialTransfer library is newer than the version that gets installed from PyPI so I've tried to link to correct version of the files on GitHub when they differ from the latest. E.g. the examples directory.

